# Tab key does not focus on input and links

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am working in wordpress.I have created jquery for focus input and links while pressing tab key.My jquery is like this:

```
jQuery('.input').bind('keydown',function(e){
        //e.preventDefault() ;
        var code = e.which;
        //alert(code);
        if(code == 9)
        {   
            var tab = jQuery(this).attr('tabindex');
            tab++;
            jQuery('[tabindex="' + tab + '"]').next().focus();
        }

    });
```

And html code is:

```
<div class="simplemodal-login-fields">
   <p>
      <label>
      E-mail
      <input class="user_login input" type="text" tabindex="1" size="20" value="" name="log">
      </label>
   </p>
   <p>
      <label>
      Password
      <input class="user_pass input" type="password" tabindex="2" size="20" value="" name="pwd">
      </label>
   </p>
   <p class="forgetmenot">
       <label>
       <input id="rememberme" class="rememberme input" type="checkbox" tabindex="3" value="forever" name="rememberme">
       Remember Me
       </label>
   </p>
   <p class="submit">
       <input class="input" type="submit" tabindex="4" value="Log In" name="wp-submit">
       <input class="simplemodal-close input" type="button" tabindex="5" value="Cancel">
       <input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie">
   </p>
   <p class="nav">
       <a class="simplemodal-register input" tabindex="6" href="http://toleratedmerge.lancetek.com/register-2/">Register</a>
       |
       <a class="simplemodal-forgotpw input" tabindex="7" title="Password Lost and Found" href="http://toleratedmerge.lancetek.com/lostpassword/">Lost your password?</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

Now, When I press tab key it will focus only text field and links.It does not focus on remember checkbox,login and cancel button.So what should I have to do to focus on login and register buttons?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `.next()`? Looks like in your case it doesn't match any element

Comment: Browsers already have the functionality built in using the `tabIndex` property which you seem to be re-purposing. Is there a specific reason you're doing it this way?

Comment: your code works fine in the Code snippet without the jquery

Comment: you dont need the jquery code for tabbing, Its automatically handled by browser https://jsfiddle.net/yrmuzkcb/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 
 
I have used jquery for focusing on link.Because when i remove my jquery it will not focus on link.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery code is breaking the native browser behavior. Remove it and it'll work fine. Remember you have to put them all in a single form tag for focus to work. tab would only focus in the same form elements.

```
<div class="simplemodal-login-fields">
   <p>
      <label>
      E-mail
          <input class="user_login input" type="text" tabindex="1" size="20" value="" name="log" />
      </label>
   </p>
   <p>
      <label>
      Password
          <input class="user_pass input" type="password" tabindex="2" size="20" value="" name="pwd" />
      </label>
   </p>
   <p class="forgetmenot">
       <label>
           <input id="rememberme" class="rememberme input" type="checkbox" tabindex="3" value="forever" name="rememberme" />
       Remember Me
       </label>
   </p>
   <p class="submit">
       <input class="input" type="submit" tabindex="4" value="Log In" name="wp-submit" />
       <input class="simplemodal-close input" type="button" tabindex="5" value="Cancel" />
       <input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie" />
   </p>
   <p class="nav">
       <a class="simplemodal-register input" tabindex="6" href="http://toleratedmerge.lancetek.com/register-2/">Register</a>
       |
       <a class="simplemodal-forgotpw input" tabindex="7" title="Password Lost and Found" href="http://toleratedmerge.lancetek.com/lostpassword/">Lost your password?</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

[check here](https://jsfiddle.net/mjdm84rb/)

Comment: I remove my jquery then it focus buttons but does not focus link.

Comment: well this might be a browser related problem. in google chrome link is focused. which browser are you using?

Comment: I have used mozila firefox.

Comment: This is my [website](http://toleratedmerge.lancetek.com/).Open it and click on login popup will be open then press tab key.

Comment: The reason is Register and Lost Password links are in a different `<form>` tag from your user login form. You need to encapsulate them in the same form tag for focus to work.

Comment: I have checked it.Both are in the same form.